# Check if an entry exists as a fact

Tags: prolog

Just wondering why this simple code won't work as intended:

```
validAlloc(Reg, Reg, Reg, Reg, Reg) :- register(Reg).
```

Basically I wanted to check that if the user enters validAlloc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) that those numbers exist within register. My problem is it only works if every single one of the numbers is the same. But i want the user to be able to enter a combination of different numbers that exist.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the above is not working is that when you write the rule

```
validAlloc(Reg, Reg, Reg, Reg, Reg)
```

prolog takes that all five parameters are the same (because they are all named Reg).

One simple answer is:

```
validAlloc(Reg, Reg1, Reg2, Reg3, Reg4) :-
    register(Reg),register(Reg1),register(Reg2),register(Reg3),register(Reg4).
```

Another more elegant solution would be:

```
validAlloc2([]).
 validAlloc2([H|T]) :- register(H),validAlloc2(T).
```

in the above you provide a list of (five) elements and not five numbers.

If you need to work exactly like before you could simply write:

```
validAlloc(Reg, Reg1, Reg2, Reg3, Reg4):-
  validAlloc2([Reg, Reg1, Reg2, Reg3, Reg4]).
```

where `validAlloc2` is defined above.

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense. I had mistaking assumed that prolog saw reg as a list of all entries that were valid for reg.

Comment: Or simply, `maplist(register, RegValues)`.